# Appium could not start a new session

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm trying to launch my app from Android app in my mac using Appium.app
or using my code but I'm getting an error as

Could not start a new session.

Be sure the Appium server is running with an application opened by
using the "App Path" parameter in Appium.app (along with package and
activity for Android) or by connecting with selenium client and
supplying this in the desired capabilities object."

```
Launching Appium with command: export     
ANDROID_HOME="/Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/"; 
'/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node'             
appium/build/lib/main.js --port "4724" --session-override --debug-log-    
spacing --automation-name "Appium" --platform-name "Android" --
platform-version "4.4" --app     "/Users/user1/WorkSpace/Automation/automation/automation_tests/selenium/src    /test/resources/myApp.apk" --full-reset --dont-stop-app-on-reset --avd     
"10_1_WXGA_Tablet_API_24" --app-pkg "com.myApp.com" --app-activity     
"com.myApp.com.activities.MainActivity" --app-wait-package     
"com.myApp.com" --app-wait-activity 
"com.myApp.com.activities.AndroidDatabaseManager" --device-name 
"10_1_WXGA_Tablet_API_24" --language "en" --intent-action     
"android.intent.action.MAIN" --intent-category 
"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.5.3

[Appium] Non-default server args:

[Appium]   port: 4724
[Appium]   sessionOverride: true
[Appium]   debugLogSpacing: true
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '4.4'

[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   deviceName: '10_1_WXGA_Tablet_API_24'
[Appium]   app:     
'/Users/user1/WorkSpace/Automation/automation/automation_tests/selenium/src
/test/resources/MyApp.apk’
[Appium]   language: 'en'
[Appium]   fullReset: true
[Appium]   appPackage: 'com.myapp.com’
[Appium]   appActivity: 'com.myapp.MainActivity'
[Appium]   appWaitPackage: 'com.myApp.com'
[Appium]   appWaitActivity: 
'com.myApp.com.activities.AndroidDatabaseManager'
[Appium]   avd: '10_1_WXGA_Tablet_API_24'
[Appium]   dontStopAppOnReset: true
[Appium] Deprecated server args:
[Appium]   --platform-name => --default-capabilities     
'{"platformName":"Android"}'
[Appium]   --platform-version => --default-capabilities     
'{"platformVersion":"4.4"}'
[Appium]   --automation-name => --default-capabilities 
'{"automationName":"Appium"}'
[Appium]   --device-name => --default-capabilities     
'{"deviceName":"10_1_WXGA_Tablet_API_24"}'
[Appium]   --app => --default-capabilities     
'{"app":"/Users/user1/WorkSpace/Automation/automation/_automation_tests/sel    enium/src/test/resources/myApp.apk"}'
[Appium]   --language => --default-capabilities '{"language":"en"}'

[Appium]   --full-reset => --default-capabilities '{"fullReset":true}'
[Appium]   --app-pkg => --default-capabilities     
'{"appPackage":"com.myApp.com"}'
[Appium]   --app-activity => --default-capabilities     
'{"appActivity":"com.myApp.com.activities.MainActivity"}'
[Appium]   --app-wait-package => --default-capabilities 
'{"appWaitPackage":"com.myApp.com"}'
[Appium]   --app-wait-activity => --default-capabilities     
'{"appWaitActivity":"com.myApp.com.activities.AndroidDatabaseManager"}'
[Appium]   --avd => --default-capabilities     
'{"avd":"10_1_WXGA_Tablet_API_24"}'
[Appium]   --dont-stop-app-on-reset => --default-capabilities     
'{"dontStopAppOnReset":true}'
[Appium] Default capabilities, which will be added to each request     
unless overridden by desired capabilities:

[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'

[Appium]   platformVersion: '4.4'
[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   deviceName: '10_1_WXGA_Tablet_API_24'
[Appium]   app: 
'/Users/user1/WorkSpace/Automation/automation/automation_tests/selenium/src
/test/resources/myApp.apk'
[Appium]   language: 'en'
[Appium]   fullReset: true
[Appium]   appPackage: 'com.myApp.com'
[Appium]   appActivity: 'com.myApp.com.activities.MainActivity'
[Appium]   appWaitPackage: 'com.myApp.com'
[Appium]   appWaitActivity: 
'com.myApp.com.activities.AndroidDatabaseManager'
[Appium]   avd: '10_1_WXGA_Tablet_API_24'
[Appium]   dontStopAppOnReset: true

[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4724

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []





[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 24

[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...

[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/platform-
tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-
5554","shell","getprop","persist.sys.locale"]
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'persist.sys.locale': 
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...

[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/platform-
tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-
5554","shell","getprop","ro.product.locale"]

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status - - ms - - 

[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.locale': en-US

[debug] [ADB] Setting device property 'persist.sys.locale' to 'en'
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/platform-
tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-
5554","shell","setprop","persist.sys.locale","en"]

[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...

[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/platform-
tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","stop"]

[debug] [ADB] Running /Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/platform-
tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","stop"]



[AndroidDriver] Cannot shut down Android driver; it has already shut     
down

[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error     
executing adbExec. Original error: Command 
'/Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 
emulator-5554 shell stop' exited with code 
1{"stdout":"","stderr":"stop: must be root\n","code":1}
    at ADB.execFunc$ (lib/tools/system-calls.js:189:13)
    at tryCatch 
(/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modul
es/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke]     (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modul    es/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as 
throw] 
(/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modul    es/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke     
(/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modul    es/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at run     
(/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modul    es/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-    
js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
    at     
/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_module    s/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-    
js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
    at flush 
(/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modul    es/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Below is my Appium logs
what is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? Even I am stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
emulator-5554 shell stop' exited with code 
1{"stdout":"","stderr":"stop: must be root\n","code":1}
```

This may be a problem with how you installed node. How did you install it? If you installed node via the quick install of nodejs site, try uninstall and install again using homebrew.

Comment: Hi, Tried installing node with homebrew but still getting same error

Comment: Sorry, this is quite a complicated scenario. I have done this before as part of my job, and there are numerous things that can be the cause. Wish you best of luck. I know you will figure it out using google searches.

I'm sure it has something to do with permissions as the log states.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it fixed. Here is the solution that worked for me:

I changed multiple things and finally got it correct. Looks more like a configuration issue on my machine.

Below is now my settings for appium application (yet to convert it to java code):

1. Install appium from brew
2. Install node from brew
3. In Appium settings, made server address to run on a different port than regular 4723 (mine was 4724)
4. In Appium settings, enabled "Over ride Existing sessions" from settings in appium
5. In Appium settings, kill processor using server port before launch
6. In Android settings, enable "Full Reset"
7. In Android settings, "Intent Action"
8. In Android settings, "Intent Category"
9. In Android settings, "Device ready timeout" 5s